# java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect, isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)

Tags: java, android, rest, jsp, tomcat

I'm trying to connect Tomcat server from Android by using Rest and post

This is the part of Post and Response

```
public void networkServiceModule(String ID, String Pwd){
        Log.d("networkServiceModule","ID : "+ID);
        Log.d("networkServiceModule","PW : "+Pwd);

        Call<PostJson> thumbnailCall = ApplicationController.buildNetworkService().postLogin(new PostJson(ID,Pwd));
        thumbnailCall.enqueue(new Callback<PostJson>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<PostJson> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                if(response.isSuccess()) {
                    String resultCode = response.body().getResult_code().toString();
                    Log.d("networkServiceModule", "response Code : "+resultCode);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login : " + resultCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    int statusCode = response.code();
                    Log.d("networkServiceModule", "response Code : "+statusCode);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                Log.d("onFailure", "onFailure Code "+t.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

but this error occurs whenever I press 'login' button.

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.147 (port 8080) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
```

Here's some code of login.jsp

```
<body>
    <%
        int login_status = 0; //0: empty data, 1: login success, 2: wrong pwd, 3: id not found
        String ID = request.getParameter("id");
        String PW = request.getParameter("pw");

        String str = null;
        String url = "http://192.168.1.6:8080/Attendance/login.jsp";

        if (ID == null)
            login_status = 0;
        else if (PW == null)
            login_status = 0;
        else {
            Connection conn = null;
            Statement stmt = null;
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "root", "1234");

                if (conn == null)
                    throw new Exception("db connection failed");

                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM lists WHERE Email = '" + ID + "';");

                if (rs.next()) { //existing ID
                    String Email = rs.getString("Email");
                    String Passwd = rs.getString("Passwd");
                    if (PW.equals(Passwd)) {    //1: login success
                        login_status = 1;
                    }

                ... 

        }

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("result_code", login_status);        
        out.print(jsonObject);

    %>
</body>
```

is there anything wrong with .jsp ?

I wanted to print json which just has single int(result_code) as response for java(Android studio).

And here's my NetworkService interface and PostJson class on studio

```
public interface NetworkService {
    @POST("/Attendance/login.jsp")
    Call<PostJson> postLogin(@Body PostJson postJson);

    @GET("/Attendance/login.jsp")
    Call<Login> getLogin();
}
```

--

```
public class PostJson {
    String id;
    String pw;
    public PostJson(String Id, String Pw){
        id = Id;
        pw = Pw;
    }

    String result_code;
    public String getResult_code(){
        return result_code;
    }
}
```

I'm a just beginner in programming.
Your comments will be such a great help for me.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: basic question your device and server are sharing same wifi?

Comment: Likewise, if your server has any accessible web pages, can you access them from your phone's web browser? I suspect this is a network issue.

Comment: Yes, they are using same wifi, and I can access to server web pages through my phone's web browser..

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, it was a port problem :)